# making flow chart with java script

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm new in JavaScript.

I try to write a code that you can make flow chart with it.
when you click on shapes in left side they will copy on right menu and you can write in them.
but I have a problem.
I want to change the position of shapes in right side by mouse, I can't write its function.

here is my code

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var drag = false
  let objects = document.getElementsByClassName('object')
  for (var i in objects) {
    objects[i].onclick = function() {
      let data = this.outerHTML.replace('object', 'object dynamic')
      document.getElementById('rightmenu').innerHTML += data
      for (var j in document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic")) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic")[j].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        
          // this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'

        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.diamond {
    rotate: 45deg;
    background-color: orchid;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.rectangle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}

.line {
    width: 3px !important;
    height: 115px !important;
    background-color: black;
}

.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}

.mainblock {

    height: 80vh;
    width: 60vw;
    max-width: 20px auto;
}

.leftmenu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#rightmenu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 79%;
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="js.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainblock">
        <div class="leftmenu">
            <input class="object diamond"> </input>
            <input class="object circle"> </input>
            <input class="object rectangle">
            <div class="object line"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="rightmenu"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: Also PLEASE delegate. You are adding mouse event listeners in a loop on a click in a loop

Comment: thank you. here you are

Comment: Please add the `dynamic` elements